# How to remove edit button from showdatepicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the `showDatePicker` to display the date and get the selected date but I don't need the above edit button, so how I can remove or disable it

My code :

```
showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          lastDate:
              DateTime.parse('2051-08-30'))
      .then((value) {
    cubit.getDateTime(
        date: value.toString());
  });
```

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
```

Comment: it's in flutter 2 and above not in flutter 1 ( sdk 1.22.4)